# How to pass context to done in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Following is the scenario :

```
getSomething: function(){
    var gotValue = sendAjax();
    gotValue.done(function(response){
        console.log(response); //How to pass context of object to call getSomethingElse
        //getSomethingElse();
    });
},
getSomethingElse : function(){
}
```

I want to call the getSomethingElse function in the done method of the ajax

Comment: You can use apply,call to pass the object reference. If you always want to getSomethingElse being called with some reference..Use bind https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$this=this;` since the `this` in the function is not referring to the object.

```
getSomething: function()
{
var $this = this;
var gotValue = sendAjax();
gotValue.done(function(response){
   console.log(response);
   $this.getSomethingElse();
});
},
getSomethingElse : function()
{
}
```

Or you can use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
gotValue.done($.proxy(function(response){
   console.log(response);
   this.getSomethingElse();
},this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reference to current context:

```
getSomething: function () {
    var self = this;
    sendAjax().done(function (response) {
        self.getSomethingElse(response);
    });
    // or even shorter: sendAjax().done(self.getSomethingElse);
},
getSomethingElse: function () {}
```

Using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
getSomething: function () {
    sendAjax().done(function (response) {
        this.getSomethingElse(response);
    }.bind(this));
},
getSomethingElse: function () {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var someHelper = {

    getSomething : function() {

        var gotValue = sendAjax();

        //keep a reference to the obj, normally "this", or "someHelper" 
        var self = this; 

        gotValue.done(function(response) {

            console.log(response); //How to pass context of object to call getSomethingElse
            //getSomethingElse();

            //call getSomethingElse
            self.getSomethingElse();
        });
    },
    getSomethingElse : function() {

    }
}
```